# file.each_char not working right after a file.each_line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I am trying to do `file.each_char` right after a `file.each_line`, but it never gets called when it is like this. If I get rid of the `file.each_line`, the `file.each_char` call works perfectly.

Here's my code for reference:

```
file.each_line do |line|
  if line =~ /^\s*$/
    next
  end
  lines += 1
end

file.each_char do |char|
  if char =~ /\s/
    next
  end
  chars += 1
end
```

How can I manage a `file.each_char` call right after `file.each_line`?

Comment: Because you are at the end of the file after doing `file.each_line`?

Comment: What is the `lines += 1` and `chars += 1` for?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: They just increment a counter that's keeping track of the number of characters and lines.

Comment: Consider using the Enumerable#count method, in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `each_line`, it leaves it pointing at the end of your IO stream (in this case a file). To iterate over the whole file a second time, you'll need to reset it to point at the beginning of the stream. `IO#rewind` will do this for you:

```
file.each_line do |line|
  if line =~ /^\s*$/
    next
  end

  lines += 1
end

file.rewind

file.each_char do |char|
  if char =~ /\s/
    next
  end

  chars += 1
end
```